# Caption uncentering its image

Tags: css, wordpress, caption

I have a problem that might be a simple one, but can't find a solution.

I am managing my self-hosted wordpress, and am often adding pictures to articles I post, and like to have them centered. However, I noticed that when adding a caption to the centered pictures, they ended up aligned left. You can see an example [here](http://themikal.com/?p=1948) (first and second pictures).

The "no caption & aligned" picture code is:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <a rel="attachment wp-att-1949" href="http://themikal.com/?attachment_id=1949">
        <img class=" size-large wp-image-1949 aligncenter" title="hildolfr1" src="http://themikal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/hildolfr1-566x400.jpg"alt="" width="391" height="276" />
    </a>
</p>
```

Whereas the "caption and disaligned" picture code would be:

```
[caption id="attachment_1949" align="aligncenter" width="391" caption="Hildolfr"]
    <a rel="attachment wp-att-1949" href="http://themikal.com/?attachment_id=1949">
        <img class=" size-large wp-image-1949 aligncenter  " title="hildolfr1" src="http://themikal.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/hildolfr1-566x400.jpg" alt="" width="391" height="276" />
    </a>
[/caption]
```

I tried adding `<p style="text-align: center;"></p>` to the captioned picture code, either outside the caption brackets or inside, but without results.

Would someone have an idea about why it reacts like that? [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42886/caption-uncentering-its-image) decided it was a css-related issue, and so was more relevant here.

I am a total beginner regarding CSS, and am using a predesigned code that I then heavily modified. But I can give more info about some info in the CSS if someone points where it is located.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The caption under second image on page you linked to is centered on my browser (Chrome v17). What browser do you use?

Comment: Same. Using Firefox latest build. I suggest you try a different browser and / or a portable (self contained) version to make sure it's not a plugin mucking you up.

Comment: Strange. I am using Chrome v17 too, and up to date. Is the image centered too? I want the image to be centered, but it always end up left-aligned as soon as I put a caption.

Comment: It's also centred in IE9 on Windows 7. Your CSS code .wp-caption {text-align: center;} is doing the trick.

Comment: Image as well as text is centered in IE, FF, GG, Safari and Opera. Maybe post a pic of the problem!

Comment: Damn, it's centered on my Firefox too, and now also on Chrome. I did a small modification just before asking this question, I guess it worked. I am really sorry and embarassed about that, should I delete the question?

Comment: @Mikalichov yes, image is centered as well.

Comment: @Mikalichov If you think that what you did would provide help for others in future then you can add that as an answer and accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: by the way there is no <caption> element or attribute for the <img /> element. There is one for the <table>. <figcaption> is maybe in HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As embarassing as it is, I fixed the problem a few minutes before asking the question without realizing it.

The CSS was missing the following lines:

```
img.alignright {float:right; margin:0 0 1em 1em}
img.alignleft {float:left; margin:0 1em 1em 0}
img.aligncenter {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}
.alignright {float:right; }
.alignleft {float:left; }
.aligncenter {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto}
```

So it was not able to understand what `img class = aligncenter` could mean. Adding the lines back fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh, I took it all directly from there: http://codex.wordpress.org/Wrapping_Text_Around_Images haha; what makes them bad class names, if I may ask?

Comment: http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-tips/css-tip-2-structural-naming-convention-in-css/